# Export tool for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, data-liberation

I'm currently dumping my old BlackBerry curve (BB-OS 7) for something a bit newer.

Is there a tool that would make it possible to export all data it holds to a standard format?

Nice feature could include:

- csv export for contacts
- note export to .txt format.
- Runs on Linux (preferred), Windows or on the phone itself.

I don't really care what format it exports to, but I want it to be standard so I can easily process the data afterwards.

Comment: What are you converting to? What mail service for example? Blackberry 7 BES to a new device synced through ActiveSync to Exhange will not be an issue.

Comment: An Android device